# Managing Phone Calls when in a PhoneGap Application

Tags: cordova

I thought this would have been pretty standard, but after a good hour of searching I can't find it, this might be as simple as a lack of correct vocabulary, so feel free to make fun of me if it is.

I have a PhoneGap application built and have realized that receiving a phone call while using the app gets in the way of the experience.

Now I understand why the phone call trumps the app in priority, however is there a way that I can manage the phone call so that you can see who is calling and even put up an accept / decline so that you can continue to use the app while managing incoming phone calls?

So far my search has been to look through Google, and then look through PhoneGap Plugins. Nothing seems to stand out. Again thinking that this is a fairly common issue, my initial feeling is I don't have the right vocabulary to search for this.

Comment: It would be unlikely for Cordova to attempt to deal with an issue like this each phone platform is going to be different in how it deals with phone calls. 
Also, when you say, 'gets in the way of the experience', what exactly do you mean? Which phone platform have you tried this on?

Comment: This a group quiz that is scored based on time of response. When testing those who caught on quickly would phone competitors to put them off and run down their timer. People can be dicks sometimes. I've tried this on iOS and Android. However each phone deals with a plethora of things differently and with the language differences you could argue it deals with absolutely everything differently. I am hoping to find a way to manage an incoming call. If I can't I need to redesign the system and with the response here so far, that looks like where I'm headed. Perhaps a game mechanic can fix this.

Comment: When you receive a phone call, the operating system interrupt your app, that happens on phonegap and native apps. On phonegap the pause event is called, try to manage your game logic there to pause the game